# Creating a loop for list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

How do I create a loop which loops through the 'prices' for `"productType":"WIN_ODDS_BSP"`.

Here is an example of the JSON:

```
"runners":[{"selectionId":"24369070",
            "runnerName":"Bloomin Crafty",
            "barrierNo":3,
            "saddleClothNo":1,
            "placedResult":2,
            "startingPosition":1,
            "trainerName":"Kathryn Durden",
            "jockeyName":"Jarrod Fry",
            "weight":58.0,
            "silkColor":"Hot Pink Royal Blue Horseshoe Hot Pink Royal Blue \u0026 White Checked Sleeves \u0026 Cap",
            "colorURL":"c20200713MURT/1364572.png",
            "bestTote":10.4,
            "markets":[{"productType":"WIN_ODDS_BSP",
                        "price":10.09,
                        "reductionFactor":8.33,
                       {"productType":"PLACE_ODDS_BSP",
                        "price":2.92,
                        "reductionFactor":13.85
                       }],
            "bestNZTote":0}]
```

Here is my code, which works up until the last line:

```
for marketid in marketids:
    request2 = requests.get(f'https://betfair-data-supplier-prod.herokuapp.com/api/race_results/?market_id=1.{marketid}&nz_tote_event_id=',
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    json2 = request2.json()
    for runner in json2['runners']:
        for market in runner['markets']:
            if market['productType'] in ['WIN_ODDS_BSP']:
                for p in market['price']:
```

Comment: I would guess p is a field, not a table.

Comment: `market['price']` is not a list why are you using loop here? and you can change your if statement like this `market.get(productType) == 'WIN_ODDS_BSP'` and then you can access price using `market['price']`

Answer (score 1):

The code below will extract the prices as a list from `markets` key, then you can decide what to do with the list:

```
for runner in json2['runners']:
    prices = [p.get('price') for p in runner.get('markets') if p.get('productType') == 'WIN_ODDS_BSP']

prices
```

Output:

```
[10.09]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code-line:

```
if market['productType'] in ['WIN_ODDS_BSP']
```

of your code-snippet to:

```
if market['productType'] == 'WIN_ODDS_BSP'
```

this helps you to filter the object of **product WIN_ODDS_BSP**
once after filtering, you can acces the price by:

```
market['price']
```

This market['price'] gives you float value not a list. So you can not use for loop there(the last line in your code-snippet):

```
for p in market['price']
```

If you wish to store value of market['price'] in 'p' variable, then below code-snippet will be you are looking for:

```
for market in runner['markets']:
  if market['productType'] == 'WIN_ODDS_BSP':
    p = market['price']:
```